# ajax request does not show proper data in firefox, but works in chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

This is my

```
function getABC(x) {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "abcd.do",
            data: {abc: x},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Here, alert box shows proper data in Chrome and IE, but gives '[XML Document]' when ran in firefox(irrespective of operating system).
Can someone tell what could be possible solution.

Comment: Add dataType: "text" property to the request so it will always return plain xhr.responseText instead of intelligent type which is default and creates response based on MIME type. Another option is to use third argument in success function and to use directly xhr.responseText.

Comment: yea, 'text' thing worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Parsing the XML Object into JS Object and continue

```
function getABC(x) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "abcd.do",
        data: {abc: x},
        success: function (data) {
            var xmlObject = $.parseXML(data);
            alert(xmlObject);
            console.log(xmlObject);
        }
    }
    );
}
```